# Final size of a structure variable of data structure "stack" (implementation through structure and its creation through function)

Tags: c

So I am learning about data structure `stack` in my college, howsoever I have some doubts in its implementation and the memory it occupies.

Below is a small code which I have written for it: -

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdbool.h>

struct stack
{
    int *array;
    int top;
    int max_size;
};


struct stack createStack(int size)
{
    struct stack *Stack = malloc(sizeof(struct stack)); //line 1
    Stack -> max_size = size; //line 2
    Stack -> top = -1; //line 3
    Stack -> array = calloc(Stack -> max_size, sizeof(int)); //line 4
    return *Stack;
}

int main()
{
    int size; //Here lets say that size = 5
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("%ld", sizeof(createStack(size)));

    return 0;
}
```

Here I have defined Stack through `struct stack` as seen below in this portion of the code: -

```
struct stack
{
    int *array;
    int top;
    int max_size;
};
```

Now the memory which would be occupied by the above `struct stack` should be: -

> `8 bytes` for `int *array`
>
> `4 bytes` for `int top`
>
> `4 bytes` for `int max_size`

Therefore total memory occupied\allocated should be `16 bytes`.

Now lets come to the second portion of code which helps in creation of `stack`: -

```
struct stack createStack(int size)
{
    struct stack *Stack = malloc(sizeof(struct stack)); //line 1
    Stack -> max_size = size; //line 2
    Stack -> top = -1; //line 3
    Stack -> array = calloc(Stack -> max_size, sizeof(int)); //line 4
    return *Stack;
}
```

> Here in `line 1` we have allocated the sizeof `struct stack`(`16 bytes`) in **structure variable** `*Stack`. Hence size of `* Stack` is `16 bytes`.
>
> In `line 2` and in `line 3` values are initialised.
>
> Now my question come from `line 4`

In `line 4` we allocated `20 bytes` to `int *array` (considering `max_size = 5`)

Now shouldn't the size of **structure variable** `*Stack` be `28 bytes` considering that `int *array` now occupies `20 bytes` instead of `8 bytes` ?

When I run the above code, it still mentions that the `sizeof` **structure variable** `*Stack` is `16 bytes`. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now shouldn't the size of structure variable `*Stack` be 28 bytes considering that `int *array` now occupies 20 bytes instead of 8 bytes?

No. The size of `array` is still 8 bytes. It just contains the memory address of a separate chunk of memory that is 20 bytes in size. That separate chunk is not part of `*Stack` and does not contribute to its size.

In fact, `sizeof(createStack(size))` does not call your function, so no memory is ever allocated. `sizeof` only cares about the type of its operand expression. Since `createStack` is declared as returning a `struct stack`, `sizeof createStack(...)` is equivalent to `sizeof (struct stack)`. All of this is resolved at compile time.

Similarly, if you do

```
char arr[1000];
char *ptr = &arr[0];
```

then `sizeof ptr` is still 8 because `ptr` is declared as `char *` and `sizeof (char *)` is 8. That's all that matters.

---

By the way, if you were to actually call `createStack`, it would leak memory:

```
    struct stack *Stack = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    ...
    return *Stack;
```

The first line allocates memory and stores the address in `Stack`. However, this address does not leave the function. Only a copy of the struct itself is returned (via `return *Stack`). The program has now lost track of the pointer returned by `malloc` and can never `free` it.

Fix:

```
    struct stack Stack;
    Stack.max_size = size;
    Stack.top = -1;
    Stack.array = calloc(Stack -> max_size, sizeof(int));
    return Stack;
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of a structure is just the amount of memory used for the structure itself, not the memory for any things pointed to be members of the structure.

The fact that `array` is given a value that points to more memory does not change the structure or its size.

`sizeof` reports only the memory required for a particular object. It does not report all memory you have associated or linked to in some way.